# Attend an international conference during PhD? How to know I'm ready (or not) to attend/answer a call for paper?

Tags: conference

I am currently a Ph.D. candidate (1st year). I am still reviewing literature and thinking about the design of my research to begin the empirical part within 4–6 months (social sciences, qualitative research).

There is an international conference organizing different seminars about themes I precisely deal with. Though I still did not start the empirical part, I would like to know if it is of any interest to answer a call for contribution to discuss the theoretical framework I contemplate to build upon?

My supervisor seems not knowing yet that this conference is organized (his research interests are quite far from that of the conference). I fear it might sounds being fiercely ambitious, though I consider this meeting as an opportunity to meet people sharing my research interests/challenging my first assumptions.

Comment: You can still ask your advisor.

Comment: This is totally dependent on when the call is due